# Stuck on "Partitioning disk..."

Tags: macos, bootcamp, partition, catalina

I have been trying to download bootcamp for a while now, but every time it gets stuck on Partitioning disk... and "The system may be unresponsive"

I have already looked at applesupport for this but they say that there should be the disks OSXRESERVED and BOOTCAMP, but these are not showing up for me.

[image: Disk Utility]
[image: BootCamp Assistant]

Comment: Is this an HDD or an SSD? And how much disk space did you assign to the Windows partition?

Comment: If you try to shrink a APFS container to create space for new partitions, you will get a warning message stating this will take a long time and you should first boot to recovery mode. The Boot Camp Assistant (BCA) therefore probably will take a long time to partition the drive for a Windows install. You will have to be patient. I have a 2013 iMac. Using the BCA to install, with a JHFS+ partition for macOS, did not take very long. Recently, I did a clean install using a APFS container partition for macOS. Installing Windows, by using the BCA, did take a significantly longer time to complete.

Comment: I should point out the 2013 iMac has a SATA 1 TB HDD. I also have a 2018 mac mini with a very fast PCIe 256 GB SSD. Here, macOS is installed in a APFS container partition. Installing Windows using the BCA was much faster than when installing on the 2013 iMac. In other words, APFS container partitions can take a long time to shrink if done live. The shrinking should be done when the APFS container is offline. Unfortunately, the BCA requires the shrinking to be done live.